# Task has been stopped errors shown in this place of setContentView

Tags: android

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prabatask/com.example.prabatask.Purchase_Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #167: Binary XML file line #167: Error inflating class 
at android.app.ActivityThread

Comment: I find out  the answer,if any body have problem like this,please check XML design  uisng font like backround colors,text style place errors occured just remove using different format.